# Identify duplicate values whitin a foreach loop and assign an incrementing number to each duplicate value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach, duplicates

Here is my MySQl table

```
Id    Name   Value
1    abc     12
2    xyz     32
3    abc     43
4    cde     54
5    fgh     75
6    abc     56
7    fgh     98
```

I want to add an incrementing number to each duplicate value when its been printed using a foreach loop as shown below.

```
abc (1) = 12
abc (2) = 43
abc (3) = 56
cde = 43
fgh (1) = 75
fgh (2) = 98
xyz = 32
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.0, use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*, row_number() over(partition by name order by id) rn
from mytable t
```

If you actually want to modify the name by prefixing an incrementing value when duplicates exists:

```
select 
    case when count(*) over(partition by name) > 1 
        then concat(name, ' (', row_number() over(partition by name order by id), ')')
        else name
    end name,
    value
from mytable
```

Comment: This solution was perfect and worked in my localhost. I just realized that the MySQL version in my webserver is below 8. Is there a way to achieve the same result by using another method? Actually I do not need to prefix the name with an incrementing value, I would prefer to assign it to a new variable 'row_num'

Answer (score 1):

```
    //your db rows
    $rows = [
        ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'abc', 'value' => 12],
        ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'xyz', 'value' =>32],
        ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'abc', 'value' =>43],
        ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'cde', 'value' =>54],
        ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'fgh', 'value' =>75],
        ['id' => 6, 'name' => 'abc', 'value' =>56],
        ['id' => 7, 'name' => 'fgh', 'value' =>98],
    ];

    $data = [];
    ///select same names to array
    foreach ($rows as $row){
        if(array_key_exists($row['name'], $data)){
            array_push($data[$row['name']], $row['value']);
        }else{
            $data[$row['name']] = [$row['value']];
        }
    }

    //output result
    foreach ($data as $key => $value){
        if(count($data[$key]) === 1){
            echo $key .' = '. $value[0];
            echo '<br>';
        }else{
            foreach ($value as $k => $v){
                $k++;
                echo $key .'('.$k.') = '. $v;
                echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    }

    output
    abc(0) = 12
    abc(1) = 43
    abc(2) = 56
    xyz = 32
    cde = 54
    fgh(0) = 75
    fgh(1) = 98
```